# Did I mess anything up by re-installing node with Homebrew?

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

I originally installed Node from the website, but recently installed it again from Homebrew, because I was trying to start using Homebrew more.
Here's what I noticed: I wanted to list my global npm modules, so I ran `npm list -g | head -1`. This returned `/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.3.0/lib`, a folder that contains only the modules that I've installed since installing Node with Homebrew. If I look in `/usr/local/bin` I see all the npm modules that I installed in the past.

**What I Want To Know:**

Is this bad, that I have most of my npm modules in `/usr/local/bin` but the new ones I'm installing are going to `/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.3.0/lib`? Will there be any compatibility issues? If so, what should I do?

Comment: Deinstall the original version of node and just use a single one, the one from brew. You will have to install all globally installed npm packages again but that would be expected.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else, it will complicate debugging system issues. Having multiple versions of `npm` that install global CLIs in different places is a frequent source of StackOverflow questions. It might not cause any problems, but if you want to be careful, you should uninstall the version of Node.js you're not using along with all the global packages for that version. If you want to be super cautious, uninstall both versions, and then reinstall only one fresh. Just use a single version.

Lastly, if you need to switch between different versions of Node.js frequently, skip the installer and Homebrew entirely and use a version manager such as [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

Comment: +1 for mentioning nvm. That's the way to go, I even would put it in the top of the answer instead of the bottom.

Comment: @trott Thanks for your reply. Do you know how I would uninstall all the packages? Right now when I use `npm i -g <package>` it gets saved at `/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.3.0/bin`, so I want to delete all the old packages from `/usr/local/bin` but don't know whether I should just delete those binaries?